# Some Developer Advice

Tags: coldfusion

I am currently working on a program that I really think is a good idea (at least I sure hope it is). For the program I am building I am using (after some very long consideration) ColdFusion - Flex - Adobe Air. However, I have to learn ColdFusion to do this.

I am an independent developer that for the most part uses PHP to build my client's websites. Since I plan on learning ColdFusion to build this program, do you guys have any advice on how I can use ColdFusion elsewhere. It is not very exciting to think that I am learning this language for just one thing.

I don't plan on bulding Coca-Cola's lastest greatest website anytime soon, but I (for some odd reason) enjoy coding and was just wondering if you guys had any advice on any smaller-time avenues that one could persue??

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! :)

**Cliff notes**: I'm an independent PHP developer learning ColdFusion for a client.  Its not exciting to learn a language which I will never use again.  Where can I apply ColdFusion in the future?

Comment: It's hard to say much without understanding **why** you want to learn another "server-side web only" language/environment rather than sticking with the one you already know OR moving to a general purpose language (Java, Python, Ruby, etc) which you could then use for both server-side web apps _and_ many other kinds of codes. What killer advantages have you spotted in ColdFusion to tear you off PHP _and_ away from Java, Python, Ruby, etc?

Comment: i switched to ColdFusion because it has the 'push' feature for Adobe Air. I don't think PHP has this, I could be wrong though. My decision was between Java and ColdFusion and I ended up going with ColdFusion because the syntax made more sense to me than Java's did.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use ColdFusion to build any webapp you could build with PHP. I've seen a few articles lately with comments from PHP developers switching to ColdFusion. This one was posted today, and lists some pros and cons of switching to ColdFusion.

http://blog.rubicon.je/2009/09/coldfusion-half-a-year-away/

I wouldn't consider it an either/or proposition though. If you want to learn CF for your AIR app, it will absolutely come in handy for something else down the road, even if you don't plan for that. Knowing more than one (or three) languages is *always* beneficial, as it gives you additional insight into other ways to solve problems.

Dan

Answer (score 3):

ColdFusion or CFML the language is a tool, like any other you might add to your toolkit.  As developers I personally feel we choose choose the best tool for the job.  That said having another tool available will invariably come in handy down the road rather you write another CFML application or not.  General solid programming advice is to try and learn at least one new language a year.

CFML is easy to learn, yet also provides for advanced development, which is why many choose to go with it. I came from a PHP/Perl background and picked it up in a couple weeks.  If you are comfortable programming once you get the syntax down you can use to it do anything you can do with PHP.  I wrote at length on the comparison in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234296/coldfusion-vs-php/236077#236077).

Further lengthy Question/Answers to the viability/use of ColdFusion:

[Is ColdFusion a good choice for web development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540694/is-coldfusion-a-good-choice-for-web-development/542930)

[What is the status of ColdFusion today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191639/what-is-the-status-of-coldfusion-today/1196782)

I know you didn't ask about comparisons, you have made your decision.  For building Flex/AIR apps with a data back-end imho ColdFusion or BlazeDs is the way to go.   ColdFusion allows you to hook up the power of java to serve data with the easy of a scripting language.  With that starting point you have your foot in the Java platform which is tremendously powerful and extensive.  You can invoke interact with the Java layer and harness that power.  Many will make the leap to Java or a more "friendly" JVM language like [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) or [JRuby](http://jruby.org/).

> do you guys have any advice on how I can use ColdFusion elsewhere.

[slidesix](http://slidesix.com/) is a recent example of an interesting use of ColdFusion.  NASDAQ built  Flex/AIR [market replay application](http://www.adobe.com/newsletters/edge/august2008/articles/article4/index.html?trackingid=DLFXJ).  Also you can check [Ben Forta's site](http://www.forta.com/CF/using/) for more sites running ColdFusion to get some ideas.

But I think you already hit the nail on the head with Flex/AIR apps if you plan on making more, much of what Adobe does is work to make integration with their technologies as seamless as possible.  Honestly that alone has been what has excited me most about using CFML and the recent addition of open source alternatives in [Railo](http://www.getrailo.org/)/BlazeDs I have been building Flex apps powered by Railo/BlazeDs without paying a dime to Adobe.

I guess the bottom line is that the Java platform (via CFML) and the Flash Platform (via Flex Framework ) are both not going anywhere any time soon, and for that matter neither is PHP so I think you will have a solid set of skill from which to build on either way you go.

Answer (score 3):

ColdFusion is **huge** in Government, both at the Federal and State level. I moved to the D.C. area in large part because of the number CF jobs available around here.

So, you could always use it for gainful employment.

Update: Some links as requested

- [Ben Forta's list of sites using ColdFusion, Government category](http://www.forta.com/CF/using/list.cfm?categ_id=6)
- [Who uses ColdFusion](http://www.whousescoldfusion.com/) - a list of ColdFusion development shops
- [GotCFM?com](http://www.gotcfm.com/thelist.cfm) - a list of sites using ColdFusion; lots of government sites there (look under "N"; the "Government" category isn't fleshed out)
- [Adobe.com - abridged list of customers, some with links to case studies](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/customers/)
- [Monster.com search "coldfusion" in Washington, DC](http://jobsearch.monster.com/Search.aspx?brd=1&q=coldfusion&cy=us&where=Washington%2C%20DC&rad=20&rad_units=miles&qlt=1288951&qln=1029636&lid=371&re=130)
- [Dice.com search "coldfusion" in Washington, DC](http://seeker.dice.com/jobsearch/servlet/JobSearch?op=300&N=0&Hf=0&NUM_PER_PAGE=30&Ntk=JobSearchRanking&Ntx=mode+matchall&AREA_CODES=&AC_COUNTRY=1525&QUICK=1&ZIPCODE=&RADIUS=64.37376&ZC_COUNTRY=0&COUNTRY=1525&STAT_PROV=0&METRO_AREA=33.78715899%2C-84.39164034&TRAVEL=0&TAXTERM=0&SORTSPEC=0&FRMT=0&DAYSBACK=30&LOCATION_OPTION=2&FREE_TEXT=coldfusion&WHERE=washington%2C+dc)

Comment: could you share some links about that please?  Thanks

Comment: Don't forget UPS -- the largest non-governmental user of CF in the world.  All their internal web-based systems run on it, last time I talked to their internal devs.

Comment: Why does the govt like it so much?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a basic reading of what people are paying for via (shudder) RentACoder: http://www.google.com/search?q=coldfusion+site%3Arentacoder.com

Comment: but, honestly isn't that the same for any language?  they all seem to be targeting cheap outsourcing... which is usually Indian

Answer (score 1):

You can use coldfusion everywhere and as much as you like in PHP.  There's enough free engines (Railo, Smith, OpenBlueDragon) that you can load into Tomcat instances, or use something like stax to put a coldfusion app into the cloud.

How far you do or don't go is up to you.  I find that I write about 1/2 the code in coldfusion that I do in PHP.  Maybe it's syntax that I feel less, I don't know.

But build your first project, I think the dots to connect will become apparent on their own